# qt program deployed on mac. config file not writing when standalone app launched, works when run from within qt creator

Tags: macos, qt, deployment, config, logfile

I have a program that I have developed for mac osx. When the program is run from within Qt creator, a log file and a config.cfg file are created in the myapp.app/Contents/MacOS folder, alongside the executable. This is the correct behaviour, the program needs these files.

When I deploy the app to run standalone (by linking the required libraries using macdeploymentqt tool) the app launches and runs correctly however the log and config.cfg file do not get written to the myapp.app/Contents/MacOS folder and so settings can't be read in.

Is there anyway to get around this? Has anyone encountered this before?

Mitch

Comment: are you sure that's what you want? writing to your own app bundle is kinda discouraged and might be prevented by the system.

Comment: Well this program also runs on windows, when its implemented there the config.cfg gets written to the folder containing the executable and the required .dll files. Would there be an equivalent when compiling for mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

osx will likely not allow you writing to your bundle location on installed apps, for security reasons and because it may conflict when multiple users are using your app.

To be cross platform, you could write instead to:

```
QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppLocalDataLocation)
```

which resolves to

```
~/Library/Application Support/<APPNAME>
```

and

```
C:/Users/<USER>/AppData/Local/<APPNAME>
```

or equivalent on windows.

Comment: thanks for that! I've had a look at the documentation for QStandardPaths, I'm still a little confused on the implementation. I want to use the DocumentsLocation folder (as is needs to be a folder that is easily accessible to the user). I want to create a folder within the documents folder, when I try something like currentPath = QStandardPaths::DocumentsLocation+"/MP512"; the path becomes only MP512, any ideas?

Comment: I have got it somewhat working. by using QString path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppLocalDataLocation); currentPath = path+"/MP512";
It will return the correct directory, but the folder is not created. Will it be automatically created when the program goes to write a file there?

Answer (score 1):

You're never supposed to write to the application bundle, whether on Mac or on Windows. Even on Windows, it will not work if your user isn't an administrator. This idea last made sense on Windows 95 - not even on Windows NT. Don't do it.