# How to store INI files using QSettings on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, qt, ini, qsettings

I'm using `QSettings` to store some settings of my application in a **INI** file.

On **Windows** everything works fine and my **INI** file is stored in the same folder of my application. But on **OS X** I can't find the **INI** file, and the settings are not loaded when I open my application again.

I'm using the following code to store the values in the **INI** file using `QSettings`:

```
QSettings *settings = new QSettings("settings.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);

settings->beginGroup("AppSettings");
settings->setValue("Language", language);
settings->endGroup();
```

Does anybody knows what is happening?

How can I store INI files inside my Application.app on OS X?

Comment: What `QSettings::status()` call returns? (After attempt to write something). Are you sure that `QSettings::isWritable()` returns true?

Comment: I tried `qDebug() << settings->status();` and it returned 0.

Comment: When I run my application from Qt, `QSettings::isWritable()` returns true. But when I build it using `macdeployqt MyApp.app` and run the MyApp.app then the `QSettings::isWritable()` returns false.

Comment: My INI file finally appeared inside the MyApp->Contents->MacOS->settings.ini (possibly because I created it running the application from Qt). But, I think the INI file is not readable/writable because it is inside the MyApp.app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the **OS X** does not gives permissions to edit files inside the app bundle.

I solved the problem by changing the **INI** file location:

```
QString path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::ConfigLocation);
QSettings *settings = new QSettings(path+"/settings.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);

settings->beginGroup("AppSettings");
settings->setValue("Language", language);
settings->endGroup();
```

Now the **INI** file will be saved in the `QStandardPaths::ConfigLocation` location, that in my case is `/Users/.../Library/Preferences`

I solved the problem based on this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327857/qt-program-deployed-on-mac-config-file-not-writing-when-standalone-app-launched).